# Opening localhost:1000 in Chrome in cmd

Tags: google-chrome, cmd

I can't seem to open localhost:1000 in Chrome via cmd. I can, however, open other urls using `start chrome www.stackoverflow.com`, but when I try this with localhost:1000 it opens an empty window. Anyone know how to fix this problem?

Comment: Why not? What happens?

Comment: `start chrome localhost:1000` gives me an empty new window of Chrome.

Comment: Have you triggered localhost:1000 in other browsers. May be your website shows blank

Comment: Nope, filling in any arbitrary number gives me an empty window.

Comment: It sounds like your localhost does not have an httpd on port 1000. What are you expecting the results to be?

Comment: I expected to get a new window opened with localhost:1000 on it, but that does not seem to happen.

Comment: Chrome doesn't seem to respond to anything with a colon in it, not even internal pages such as 'about:version'...
Also that's not the correct `START` syntax, `START` is stupid and requires a window title as the first arg.
Can you do me a favor and tell us what happens if you try to open your target with `START "" chrome localhost --port=1000` ?

Comment: @Tzalumen I figured it had something to do with the colon yea, executing your command opens a new window with only 'localhost'.

Comment: @Tzalumen `start` doesn't *require* a title, but takes the first quoted parameter (if existing) as title, which is a difference (and causes a lot of confusion to newbies).

Comment: @Stephan It is required, but unmarked by Microsoft documentation. [SS64](https://ss64.com/nt/start.html) goes to the trouble of investigating behavior and bugs, and thusly marks it explicitly as required. *If failing to use a argument frequently causes a command to swallow another argument due to undocumented behavior, the first argument is required to avoid the bug.* Y'know, best habits, etc.

Comment: it's not required (try it yourself) unless you use a quoted argument, but I agree, good habit to use it anyways.

Answer (score 6):

Simply add protocol to URL.
E.g start chrome http://localhost:1000 works well.